# Como remover um tuplo de dentro de uma lista

Tags: python-3.x, lista, tuple

Boa Tarde,
Estou com um problema num trabalho que é o seguinte:
Eu tenho uma função que necessita de listas para organizar vários elementos de acordo com características pré-definidas.
A minha dúvida é como se retira um tuplo de dentro de uma lista como apresentado no exemplo:

```
[('2019-02-20', '12:30', 'iCageDoree', 'Pedro Ruivo, lisbon, (heating; doors; windows), 5*, 75, 2019-03-22, 09:15, 3523.0')]
```

Para ficar assim:

```
['2019-02-20', '12:30', 'iCageDoree', 'Pedro Ruivo, lisbon, (heating; doors; windows), 5*, 75, 2019-03-22, 09:15, 3523.0']
```

Comment: Boas, o que acontece aqui é que o que estás a usar para inserir os dados nessa lista, está enviar os dados como um tuplo. Em vez de contornares o problema com mais linhas de código, sugiro que corrijas a forma de enviar os dados para a lista de forma a que estes não sejam inseridos como um tuplo. De qualquer das formas a solução apresentada acima funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem duas maneiras de remover um item de dentro de uma lista:

- Através do comando `del`
- Através do método `remove`

**Comando `del`**

Vamos dizer que temos a seguinte lista: `listadetuplas = [(1, 2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c')]`. Para remover-se um item, sem atentar para qual seja ele, usa-se o `del` da seguinte forma:

```
del listadetuplas[1]
```

Ou seja, estamos removendo o item/tupla presente no índice/posição 1 da lista, sem importar para qual item/tupla esteja nessa posição — caso a posição dada não "exista", retornará um erro. Desse modo, nossa lista ficará assim: `[(1, 2, 3)]`.

**Método `remove`**

Considerando o mesmo exemplo de lista e o valor inicial dela, para remover-se um item específico, podemos usar o método `remove` da seguinte forma:

```
listadetuplas.remove((1, 2, 3))
```

Ou seja, estamos removendo especificamente a tupla `(1, 2, 3)` de dentro da lista, sem importar, agora, em qual posição/índice ela esteja. Desse modo, nossa lista ficaria assim: `[('a', 'b', 'c')]`.

**[Editado]**

Sendo assim, é só pegar a classe `list` e converter a tupla em lista, desse jeito:

```
list(('2019-02-20', '12:30', 'iCageDoree', 'Pedro Ruivo, lisbon, (heating; doors; windows), 5*, 75, 2019-03-22, 09:15, 3523.0'))
```

ou

```
list([('2019-02-20', '12:30', 'iCageDoree', 'Pedro Ruivo, lisbon, (heating; doors; windows), 5*, 75, 2019-03-22, 09:15, 3523.0')][0])
```

Espero ter ajudado!